# Passing ArrayList<CustomObject> along with other parameters to another activity, getting Null from arraylist

Tags: android-studio

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Model_Class dataObj = (Model_Class) intent.getSerializableExtra("value");
dataObj.getPrice();
dataObj.get_product_name();
ArrayList<InputListModleClass>  _inputList = dataObj.getInputsList();
for (int j = 0; j <_inputList.size(); j++) {
    InputListModleClass itemsObj = new InputListModleClass();
    Id =  itemsObj.getInputId();
    Lable =  itemsObj.getInputLable();
}
```

I can get all values from intent, but I am getting null in Id and Lable. How can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading from newly created object instead of element from the intent.

```
InputListModleClass itemsObj = new InputListModleClass();
```

Instead of this try:

```
InputListModleClass itemsObj = _inputList.get(j);
```

and then you should have id and label from intent.